# Save Latin characters with accents in Oracle

Tags: oracle, collation

I am reading some values that are coming from an SQL Server database with collation Latin1_General_CI_AS and saving those to the Oracle db. At the moment I can see that any **é** character is incorrectly saved as **Ã©** in the Oracle db.

I tried to specify the collation in a column in the Oracle database using the following but doesn't work. It shows *"Invalid ALTER TABLE option".*

```
ALTER TABLE <table name>
MODIFY <column name> VARCHAR2(450)
CHARACTER SET latin1
COLLATE latin1_general_ci;
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE <table name>
CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET latin1
COLLATE latin1_general_ci;
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: Oracle columns do not have a collation attribute.  A `varchar2` column will use the database's character set.  A `nvarchar2` column will use the database's national character set.  What is your database character set (query `v$nls_parameters` if you're not sure).  How are you determining that the é character is stored incorrectly?  Are you using the `dump` function?  Or is it possible that the problem is coming when you read the data?

Comment: Thanks for your response. The NLS_CHARACTERSET is UTF8.

Comment: I use INSERT into db table to save the entry into the db.

Comment: OK.  So the database is more than capable of storing every Western European character.  Have you used the `dump` function to determine whether the character is being corrupted when it is stored or when it is being read?  When you say that you are using an `insert` statement are you talking about an `insert select` across a heterogeneous database link?  Or is there some application that is reading data from one system and writing it to another?  How is that application constructed and what character set(s) is it using internally and when interacting with the databases?

Comment: An R script is reading the data from the sql server using SELECT and then it writes that data into the oracle db in combination with other columns using an INSERT. When I query the Oracle db I can see that the characters are stored differently (Ã© instead of é)

Comment: How are you querying the database?  Have you used the `dump` function to determine whether the problem is occurring when writing the data to the database or when reading the data from the database?  What character set(s) is the R script using internally and when interacting with the databases?

Comment: Usually when you expect an `é` but you get `Ã©` it means: the text is properly stored as UTF-8 in your database but your client is not able (or wrongly setup) to display it properly. The problem is being caused by UTF-8 bytes being interpreted as Windows-1252 (or ISO 8859-1) bytes. The other possibility is you actually stored `Ã©` in your database cause by wrong INSERT. As Justin ask, what do you get by `dump` function? You also use `ASCIISTR()`.

Comment: The R script is using UTF-8. 
    > select dump('Ã©',1017) from dual;
    Result: "Typ=96 Len=4 CharacterSet=UTF8: c3,83,c2,a9",
    > select dump('é',1017) from dual;
    Result: "Typ=96 Len=2 CharacterSet=UTF8: c3,a9"

    > select ASCIISTR('Ã©') from dual;
     Result: \00C3\00A9
    >select ASCIISTR('é') from dual;
    Result: \00E9

Comment: What do you get when you `select dump(column_name) from your_table` with a predicate that shows you the row in question?

Comment: I get 44 rows "Typ=1 Len=40: 82,195,131,194,...". This is the exact number of rows that contain the Ã© character.